# Validating to jsonSchema file

Tags: karate

In trying to validate our responses to the schema defined in our yamls, I have changed the yaml to a jsonSchema file.  However, for the validation itself, I recently found [this page](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/schema/schema.feature); but when trying to implement this for our response checks, I no failures.  When adjusting the yaml to trigger a fail, changing a string item to an array, float, or integer, it still seems to pass.

This yaml conversion to jsonSchema is a preferred method we would like to try and move forward with, over manually creating the schema objects, referenced as "karate's simpler alternative to json-schema"; due to the frequency of changes (new additions resulting in new versions in order to support backward compatibility) and number of different APIs in use across the organization and teams.

Calls to setup schema for checking in all responses and verify conversion to json string

```
    ##**********
    ## Schema Check setup using a third-party lib and a yaml file (converted to json schema)
    ##**********      
    * def Yaml2Json = Java.type('commonutilhelpers.YamlToJson')
    * string jsonSchema = Yaml2Json.main('src/test/java/yaml/3.23.0.yaml')
    * print jsonSchema
    * def SchemaUtils = Java.type('commonutilhelpers.SchemaUtils')
```

yaml to json conversion method

```
package commonutilhelpers;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory;

public class YamlToJson {
    public static String main(String filename) {
        String json = "";
        try {
            // System.out.println(new File(".").getCanonicalPath()); // Root path for Java
            // call
            String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filename)));
            // System.out.println("********* Content from YAML File ****************");
            // System.out.println(content);
            json = convertYamlToJson(content);
            // System.out.println("********* Converted JSON from YAML File
            // ****************");
            // System.out.println(json);
            return json;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String convertYamlToJson(String yaml) {
        try {
            ObjectMapper yamlReader = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
            Object obj = yamlReader.readValue(yaml, Object.class);
            ObjectMapper jsonWriter = new ObjectMapper();
            return jsonWriter.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(obj);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            // } catch (IOException ex) {
            // ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

schemautility method copied from karate documentation

```
package commonutilhelpers;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.github.fge.jackson.JsonLoader;
import com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.report.ProcessingReport;
import com.github.fge.jsonschema.main.JsonSchema;
import com.github.fge.jsonschema.main.JsonSchemaFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

/**
 *
 * @author pthomas3
 */
public class SchemaUtils {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SchemaUtils.class);

    public static boolean isValid(String json, String schema) throws Exception {
        JsonNode schemaNode = JsonLoader.fromString(schema);
        JsonSchemaFactory factory = JsonSchemaFactory.byDefault();
        JsonSchema jsonSchema = factory.getJsonSchema(schemaNode);
        JsonNode jsonNode = JsonLoader.fromString(json);
        ProcessingReport report = jsonSchema.validate(jsonNode);
        logger.debug("report: {}", report);
        return report.isSuccess();
    }
}
```

Is this feature no longer valid (I noticed it is dated 2018)?  Thoughts on possible issues, or recommendations that would help us utilize the yamls for schema validations?

Comment: sorry this seems to be very specific to your project and involving a lot of custom java code, I have no suggestions

Comment: I am confused by your comment as my code simply converts a yaml to a jsonSchema.  The code that is failing the assertions is from code within the karate demo - as pointed to in the "this page" link in the description and schemaUtility excerpt that I included which was authored by yourself.

Comment: as you noticed that was created in 2017, and is just an example on how to do Java interop. contributions are welcome to correct the documentation or suggest other approaches for schema validation